# MVC assigning c# list value to jquery var is giving type instead of value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@{
    var tagsList = new ArrayList();
    tagsList.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CategoryEnum)));
} 

//In html it renders: var foo = "System.Collections.ArrayList"
var foo = "@tagsList";
```

Why is the above code not getting values of `tagsList` but instead giving the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize it

```
var foo = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tagsList))
```

The above line will store all the values of the constants in the specified Enum to an Array.

`JsonConvert` is defined in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. So you need to import that to your razor view.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

If you want the names, you can use the `Enum.GetNames` method

```
var tagsList = new ArrayList();
tagsList.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(CategoryEnum)));
```

Comment: This works, but it returns the indexes of the enums, e.g. 0,1,2,3.

How do I return the values?